# How do I dispatch an action in a Redux container when using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm currently trying to implement an SPA using React, React Router, and Redux.

In this scenario, I have two hierarchical routes that share the same parent presentational and container component, but render different "child" presentational components based on the URL.

For example:

`/widgets/:slug` -> Parent + Widget detail page

`/widgets/:slug/things/:thing` -> Parent + Thing detail page

I've created the container component that will render the parent along with any children. The problem I'm having is that I think I need to dispatch an action (e.g. `fetchWidgets(slug)` from the container component, such that `mapStateToProps` will pass send the applicable props (e.g. `widget` and `thing`) to the presentational component underneath.

What I can't figure out is how to get both the `dispatch` method reference and the `props.params.slug` or `props.params.thing` property references in the same place so that I can actually dispatch the action.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the connect function provided by redux to pass state & dispatch as props into your containers.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        action: () => dispatch(actionGenerator())
    }
};

export default Container = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component);
```

Comment: But isn't that essentially making my presentational component aware of redux? I was thinking the container should be doing the actual action dispatch...

Comment: You should do this for the container component and then pass just the action as a callback prop to the presentational components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your action creator calls in one place you can send them via props to your child components.

```
<Parent
    { ...bar }
    foo={ x => actions.handlefoo(x) }
/>
```

---

```
const Child = ({
    barOne
    barTwo
    foo
}) => 
<div>
  <input onChange={ foo() } />
    {barOne}
    {barTwo}
</div>
```

Obviously this is pseudo code but it should demonstrate how simple it is to pass variables/objects of any type, including functions, to your child components.